# how can I know if the tables in the metadata are up to date to run my SAS code

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've created a SAS code that will be executed by the system on the first of each month.

How can I also add a condition to determine whether the library tables are already up to date on the same day before executing, otherwise displaying a message saying that no execution is necessary?

```
%macro Execution;
%let current_date = %sysfunc(today());
  %if (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=2 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=3 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) 

%then %do;
    %put "Le programme est en cours d'exécution ";
data TAB;
LS.RECAP;
run;
data TVA;
FALO.PERTS;
run;
/*ALL CODE.........*/
%end;
    %else %do ;
     %put " Aucune exécution nécessaire.";
     %end;
  %mend Execution ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the library's tables for the minimum modified date using `dictionary.tables`. If the lowest modified date is equal to the current date (or greater than some other specific past date), then it implies all tables in that library are current. To check for this, you will modify your code with the following changes:

```
%let current_date = %sysfunc(today());

proc sql;
    select min(datepart(modate))
    into :min_modified_date
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname IN('LS', 'FALO')
    ;
quit;

%if ( (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=2 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1)   OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=3 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) ) AND
      (&min_modified_date < &current_date)
%then %do;
```

Full code:

```
%macro Execution;
    %let current_date = %sysfunc(today());

    proc sql;
        select min(datepart(modate))
        into :min_modified_date
        from dictionary.tables
        where libname IN('LS', 'FALO')
        ;
    quit;

%if ( (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=2 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1)   OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=3 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) ) AND
      (&min_modified_date < &current_date)
%then %do;
    %put "Le programme est en cours d'exécution ";
data TAB;
LS.RECAP;
run;
data TVA;
FALO.PERTS;
run;
/*ALL CODE.........*/
%end;
    %else %do ;
     %put " Aucune exécution nécessaire.";
     %end;
  %mend Execution ;
```